# Fullpage.js snap manual scrolling to closest section

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js to make a website with different sections, and I want to have it so that a scrollbar appears so you can manually scroll but you don't have to if you don't want to. The autoscrolling works, but what I want to happen when people choose to manually move the scrollbar is that it after a delay it snaps to the nearest section.

This can be seen in [this demo made by fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/methods.html), where if you click the button to turn autoscrolling false and manually scroll down a bit, it will snap to a section.

The problem is I want to give the user an option on how to scroll, so they can either go manually (where it snaps) or automatically where scrolling autoscrolls to the next section.

Heres what I have now for settings, and when I scroll the webpage automatically it works, but when I scroll manually using the scrollbar it does not snap to a section

```
autoScrolling: true,
setAllowScrolling: true,
scrollHorizontally: false,
scrollBar: true,
fitToSection: true,
```

I am new to this, so I am not using jQuery but the vanilla javascript instead.

EDIT: Here is my [github repo](https://github.com/jaredc23/jaredc23.github.io) and the website is [jaredcohen.dev](https://jaredcohen.dev). All the relevant code is near te bottom of `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Use the fullPage.js option `scrollBar:true` combined with `autoScrolling:true`
This way you'll get the scrollbar and the user will be able to drag it or to use the trackpad/mouse wheel to snap scroll.

Here's a demo:
https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html

Comment: The demo dose not autoscroll

Comment: That demo is exactly what I want, I'm not sure then why mine is not working because I already had those settings as seen in the code I provided. I edited the post with the github repo and the website so you can see what I mean